# How to Redirect to Referrer after Accepting Terms (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, redirect, referrer

I have a script set up to require a visitor to accept terms, but I need them to be redirected to the referrer when they accept the terms without naming a specific url.

For example, I have it set up so that when a visitor clicks a link on the site to watch, say,  "video1", they must come from the terms page.  Therefore, they cannot simply enter the video's direct URL.  The script I'm using for this is as follows:

```
var requiredfrom = "form.html"; //  required prev. page
if (document.referrer.indexOf(requiredfrom) == -1) {
window.location=requiredfrom;
}
```

So, from there, when the visitor agrees to the terms on "form.html", I'd like them to automatically be redirected back to the video page that contains the above script.

javascript:history.go(-1) does not work here since the referrer is not part of the history, but I want the same effect.

This is what I am using on the terms page:

```
function defaultagree(el){
if (window.checkobj&&checkobj.checked)
//Redirect to Referrer here
else
alert("Please read/accept terms to submit form")
return false
}
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Using the "referrer" value is probably not a good idea, as it's not really reliable at all.

Comment: What happened when you tried to redirect to the referrer?

Comment: @Pointy what would you suggest?

Comment: @Humberto I haven't been able to find how to redirect to the referrer. That's what I want to do.

Comment: If the pages are all your own, have the originating page explicitly forward its URL as a parameter, or as some sort of keyword that will let your page choose from a known set of possibilities.